# Can't find point instance in order to change point shape

Tags: geometry-nodes

hi i am following Andrew's tutorial for geometry nodes but the point instance node is removed if anyone knows any alternative that would allow to change the points' (or particles') shape

here is my setup till now (notice: i used the multiply for easier density Control

[image]

this is the image from the tutorial

[image]

thanks

Comment: Or you can use V2.93

Comment: it is now called "instance on points" -> you can search for that node name

Comment: i got it thanks